# ValueError: "The estimator should be a classifier"

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, scikit-learn, ensemble-modeling

I am adapting [sklearn-extension ELMClassifier](https://github.com/wdm0006/sklearn-extensions) to be accepted as base_estimator to both `VotingClassifier` and `AdaboostClassifier`. My code works fine when i use my ELM directly with AdaboostClassifier, but since i'm going to create an Adaboost of different classifiers, i need it to be instantiated inside of VotingClassifier and then pass the VotingClassifier to the Adaboost as a base estimator.

When i run `adaboostCLF.fit(base_estimator=votingCLF, algorithm="SAMME")`, i get the following error log:

```py
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-78-25ca9de0ea07> in <module>
          1 ada2 = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=votingCLF, algorithm='SAMME')
    ----> 2 ada2.fit(X,y)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        436 
        437         # Fit
    --> 438         return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
        439 
        440     def _validate_estimator(self):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        140                 X, y,
        141                 sample_weight,
    --> 142                 random_state)
        143 
        144             # Early termination

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py in _boost(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state)
        499         else:  # elif self.algorithm == "SAMME":
        500             return self._boost_discrete(iboost, X, y, sample_weight,
    --> 501                                         random_state)
        502 
        503     def _boost_real(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_weight_boosting.py in _boost_discrete(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state)
        563         estimator = self._make_estimator(random_state=random_state)
        564 
    --> 565         estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
        566 
        567         y_predict = estimator.predict(X)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
        220         transformed_y = self.le_.transform(y)
        221 
    --> 222         return super().fit(X, transformed_y, sample_weight)
        223 
        224     def predict(self, X):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
         55     def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
         56         """Get common fit operations."""
    ---> 57         names, clfs = self._validate_estimators()
         58 
         59         if (self.weights is not None and

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
        247                 raise ValueError(
        248                     "The estimator {} should be a {}.".format(
    --> 249                         est.__class__.__name__, is_estimator_type.__name__[3:]
        250                     )
        251                 )

    ValueError: The estimator customELMClassifer should be a classifier.
```

And here is the code for the ELM i'm using:

```py
    class customELMClassifer(ELMClassifier):
        def resample_with_replacement(self, X_train, y_train, sample_weight):

            # normalize sample_weights if not already
            sample_weight = sample_weight / sample_weight.sum(dtype=np.float64)

            X_train_resampled = np.zeros((len(X_train), len(X_train[0])), dtype=np.float32)
            y_train_resampled = np.zeros((len(y_train)), dtype=np.int)
            for i in range(len(X_train)):
                # draw a number from 0 to len(X_train)-1
                draw = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(X_train)), p=sample_weight)

                # place the X and y at the drawn number into the resampled X and y
                X_train_resampled[i] = X_train[draw]
                y_train_resampled[i] = y_train[draw]

            return X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled


        def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, random_state=0):
            if sample_weight is not None:
                X, y = self.resample_with_replacement(X, y, sample_weight)

            return super().fit(X, y)
```

I'd appreciate some feedback or solution since i have no experience creating scikit-learn estimators from scratch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure AdaBoostClassifier, or any other scikit-learn kernel, accepts any classifier as `base_estimator`, and it might not accept ELMClassifier, at least for the moment. You should open an issue on Github and ask directly the scikit-learn community about that.

Comment: It does, the default is `DecisionTreeClassifier`. If the estimator implements `sample_weight`, then it can be used in Adaboost.

Answer (score 2):

that's probably due to the fact your class is not really 100% compatible to the scikit-learn estimator interface. You can easily verify this with the `check_estimator` method in `sklearn.utils.estimator_checks`. This should ensure you it is a proper classifier which can be passed then to AdaBoost.

I'd also suggest to inherit from `BaseEstimator` in addition to `ELMClassifier`.

For further details, see the instructions reported [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html) in order to create a custom (compatible to scikit-learn interface) estimator.

Answer (score 1):

From the traceback, you can find the problem [stems from here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py#L246):

```py
is_estimator_type = (is_classifier if is_classifier(self)
                     else is_regressor)

for est in estimators:
    if est not in (None, 'drop') and not is_estimator_type(est):
        raise ValueError(
            "The estimator {} should be a {}.".format(
            est.__class__.__name__, is_estimator_type.__name__[3:]
        )
    )
```

where [the definition](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/base.py#L761) for `is_classifier` is just

```py
getattr(estimator, "_estimator_type", None) == "classifier"
```

Normally, inheriting `ClassifierMixin` is good practice and will provide the attribute `_estimator_type = "classifier"`.  In this case there may be complications since `ELMClassifier` inherits from `ELMRegressor`; probably the easiest way to work around it is to add `estimator_type = "classifier"` to your `customELMClassifier`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it came from not returning the clf from my classifier functions so when I was doing:

```
def random_for():
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 5)
    clf.fit(Input, Labels)
    y_pred = clf.predict(Test_input)
    predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
    accuracy = accuracy_score(Test_Labels, predictions)
    print("Random Forest accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy*100.0))

rclf = random_for()
```

I got the same error as the OP. Whereas;

```
def random_for():
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 5)
    clf.fit(Input, Labels)
    y_pred = clf.predict(Test_input)
    predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
    accuracy = accuracy_score(Test_Labels, predictions)
    print("Random Forest accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy*100.0))

    return clf

rclf = random_for()
```

solved the problem.